# intercepting mouse scroll events

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm using this code to intercept mouse wheel events:

```
_canvas.addEventListener("mousewheel", onWheel, false);
```

Generally it works fine; however, when a higher level div doesn't fit into the screen it intercepts mouse wheel events for scrolling, so my element doesn't receive events.
How can I make my canvas always intercept mouse wheel events, when mouse cursor is over my element?

Comment: `body {overflow: hidden;}`?

Comment: @Teemu, the outer _should_ be scrolled - however, only when the mouse cursor is over it. And when the cursor is over my canvas, it should perform a different functionality defined by my wheel event handler.

Comment: Hmm... use it only when the cursor is over the canvas...